# Android Geofencing not working. onGeoQueryReady() method call everytime

Tags: android, google-maps, android-geofence

I'm working on the app who perform geofencing..
Below code take user current location and we also have a dangerous area for which we need to be geofence.
Current Location latitude, longitude  and dangerous area latitude, longitude are same but still Geofence not triggered.

I'm running this app on android oreo 8.1

Code below is written in onMapReady method.

Every time onGeoQueryReady() method called instead of onKeyEntered.

Answer (score 0):

```
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onKeyEntered: Present");
                Toast.makeText(GeofenceMapActivity.this, "onKeyEntered: Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sendNotification("MRF", String.format("%s entered the dangerous area",key));
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                Toast.makeText(GeofenceMapActivity.this, "onKeyExited: Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onKeyExited: Present");
                sendNotification("MRF", String.format("%s exit the dangerous area",key));
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                Toast.makeText(GeofenceMapActivity.this, "onKeyMoved Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("MOVE", String.format("%s move within the dangerous area [%f/%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
            }
            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                Toast.makeText(GeofenceMapActivity.this, "onGeoQueryReady() Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "Present in onGeoQueryReady: ");
            }
            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d("ERROR", ""+error);
            }
        });
```